# Disconnected remote computer's network by mistake

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-connection, vncserver

So I have put myself in an unfortunate situation. I am working remotely and I have disconnected my remote workstation's internet connection by mistake. Is there any trick to force the remote workstation to reconnect via the router?

I am using vncserver on my remote Linux workstation, and Tight-vnc on my Windows laptop which I have with me.

Comment: Just restart networking (or reboot) after logging on locally.

Comment: How was the disconnection performed? Did you disable the adapter/interface?

Comment: So there is no way to solve this issue remotely? I am 3 hours away from home, and there is no one who could reset it for me.

Comment: I disconnected it from the desktop toolbar. I wanted to reconnect to a different network on my laptop and I forgot I had my remote desktop open. @grawity

Comment: For the future, set the machine to automatically boot & reconnect after a power outage, then put an IoT mains switch at the head of the power strip. You can then effectively force-reboot it from your phone.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, I will certainly do that after this incident. I was always careful until now...

Comment: Welcome. I have to admit I haven't yet got my own IoT remote yet, though I do have a 'radio' remote that will work to do the same from anywhere in the building, for my gateway & modem which are several floors below me. The IoT is on my shopping list ;)